# Object Not Found Error with Split Function in R on Imported Data but Works Fine When Data Frame is Coded Directly

Tags: r, split

I have tried everything I can think of but still keep getting an "object not found" error on a column when I apply a split function to it. This only happens on an imported data file. When I do the same thing with a data frame I build within R Studio, it works fine. I've tried converting the column in question from character to numeric, and used the glimpse function throughout my troubleshooting session to see that at times the data types lined up in both the imported data and the directly coded/created data frame. Can anyone figure out what's going on?

The following all works beautifully to give me a count of the maximum number copies of the same title (books) on loan in a library consortium simultaneously.

```
library(tidyverse)
options(scipen = 999)
options(digits = 22)

book_id <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
start_date <- ymd(c("2017-10-28", "2017-11-17", "2018-01-16", "2018-03-10", 
            "2018-04-04", "2018-04-07", "2018-05-05", "2018-06-06", "2018-06-06", 
            "2018-06-28", "2017-11-03", "2017-11-14", "2019-04-01", "2021-05-11",
            "2022-01-09", "2022-07-11"))
end_date <- ymd(c("2017-11-17", "2018-06-06", "2018-01-30", "2018-04-25", "2018-04-10", 
          "2018-05-10", "2018-06-06", "2018-06-06", "2018-06-26", "2018-07-12", 
          "2017-12-06", "2017-12-18", "2019-04-12", "2023-01-05", "2022-12-12", 
          "2023-05-22"))
interval_date <- interval(start_date, end_date)
df_test <- data.frame(book_id, start_date, end_date, interval_date)


df_test_2 <- df_test %>%
  split(book_id) %>%
  map_dfr(\(x) mutate(x, max_overlap = max(map_int(seq(min(start_date), max(end_date), 1),
                                               \(d) sum(d %within% x$interval_date)))))
```

The df represents 2 unique titles (A and B) and a run of start/end dates during which each has circulated. FYI I have also tried it with "1" and "2" in place of "A" and "B" and it worked.

However, when I import data and run the following, I get the "object not found" error on the OCLC_Number, which I'm trying to split. That's the only time I get the error on that column.

---

```
df <- read.delim("./Resource_Sharing_Lending_Sample.txt", header = T, na.strings = "", 
             quote = "", stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(OCLC_Number = str_replace_all(OCLC_Number, regex(";.*"), "")) %>% 
  mutate(OCLC_Number = str_replace_all(OCLC_Number, regex(".*?([0-9]+).*"), "\\1")) %>%
  mutate(OCLC_Number = as.numeric(as.character(OCLC_Number))) %>% 
  mutate(Item_Sent_Date = str_replace_all(Item_Sent_Date, regex(" .*"), "")) %>%
  mutate(Item_Sent_Date = ymd(Item_Sent_Date)) %>%
  mutate(Item_Return_Date = str_replace_all(Item_Return_Date, regex(" .*"), "")) %>%
  mutate(Item_Return_Date = ymd(Item_Return_Date)) %>%
  mutate(Interval_Date = interval(Item_Sent_Date, Item_Return_Date)) %>% 
  arrange(OCLC_Number, Item_Sent_Date)

df2 %>% 
  split(OCLC_Number) %>%
  map_dfr(\(x) mutate(x, max_overlap = max(map_int(seq(min(Item_Sent_Date),
  max(Item_Return_Date), 1),
  \(d) sum(d %within% x$Interval_Date)))))
```

---

Here is the data that I'm importing (tab-delimited):

```
OCLC_Number Item_Sent_Date  Item_Return_Date
100000310   2022-11-03 21:43:09 2023-01-10 11:11:29
1000023983  2019-09-26 20:52:24 2019-11-12 10:12:30
1000023983  2021-12-09 20:38:17 2023-07-12 10:53:16
1000050643  2019-10-14 15:39:01 2020-01-03 10:01:34
1000050643  2020-08-20 16:13:00 2021-05-17 09:37:18
1000084050  2017-11-17 08:36:34 2018-06-06 15:22:18
1000084050  2018-01-16 08:23:16 2018-01-30 10:05:31
1000084050  2018-03-22 08:52:10 2018-04-05 09:56:06
1000084050  2018-05-03 21:44:42 2018-05-10 09:45:45
1000084050  2018-05-29 08:41:59 2018-06-06 13:55:03
1000084050  2018-06-06 14:16:40 2018-06-06 15:07:42
1000084050  2018-06-06 15:12:52 2018-06-26 11:15:41
1000084050  2018-06-28 08:18:35 2018-07-12 09:52:33
1000150454  2022-03-01 10:02:26 2022-04-21 10:46:02
1000150454  2022-05-15 20:32:10 2022-08-01 10:42:43
```

And, as requested, here is the dput(df2):

```
structure(list(OCLC_Number = c(100000310, 1000023983, 1000023983, 
1000050643, 1000050643, 1000084050, 1000084050, 1000084050, 1000084050, 
1000084050, 1000084050, 1000084050, 1000084050, 1000150454, 1000150454
), Item_Sent_Date = structure(c(19299, 18165, 18970, 18183, 18494, 
17487, 17547, 17612, 17654, 17680, 17688, 17688, 17710, 19052, 
19127), class = "Date"), Item_Return_Date = structure(c(19367, 
18212, 19550, 18264, 18764, 17688, 17561, 17626, 17661, 17688, 
17688, 17708, 17724, 19103, 19205), class = "Date"), Interval_Date = new("Interval", 
    .Data = c(5875200, 4060800, 50112000, 6998400, 23328000, 
    17366400, 1209600, 1209600, 604800, 691200, 0, 1728000, 1209600, 
    4406400, 6739200), start = structure(c(1667433600, 1569456000, 
    1639008000, 1571011200, 1597881600, 1510876800, 1516060800, 
    1521676800, 1525305600, 1527552000, 1528243200, 1528243200, 
    1530144000, 1646092800, 1652572800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), tzone = "UTC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

---

I would greatly appreciate any help. Also, this is my first post so if there is anything I could have done differently please let me know.

Thank you!

Joe

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(df2)`? It starts with "structure(...)". This will give us the exact structure of your data and better allow us to dive right in and try to help. Good luck!

Comment: code blocks have enclosing triple-backticks, `\`\`\``, it makes it much easier to read when code/data is not font-displayed as readable text (variable-width).

Comment: Please make sure your code is functional before hitting the "post question" button. It's frustrating when it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base::split` does not do non-standard evaluation, use `df2$OCLC_Number`.

The reason it "works" when interactive is that you have an object named `book_id` in your working environment. If the number and order of rows does not at all change from the original, then this is relatively identical, but if anything changes then you are at best going to error out (different lengths), at worst you'll silently corrupt your data (groups will be incorrect).

```r
df2 %>% 
  split(OCLC_Number) %>%
  map_dfr(\(x) mutate(x, max_overlap = max(map_int(seq(min(Item_Sent_Date),
  max(Item_Return_Date), 1),
  \(d) sum(d %within% x$Interval_Date)))))
# Error: object 'OCLC_Number' not found

df2 %>% 
  split(df2$OCLC_Number) %>%
  map_dfr(\(x) mutate(x, max_overlap = max(map_int(seq(min(Item_Sent_Date),
  max(Item_Return_Date), 1),
  \(d) sum(d %within% x$Interval_Date)))))
#    OCLC_Number Item_Sent_Date Item_Return_Date                  Interval_Date max_overlap
# 1    100000310     2022-11-03       2023-01-10 2022-11-03 UTC--2023-01-10 UTC           1
# 2   1000023983     2019-09-26       2019-11-12 2019-09-26 UTC--2019-11-12 UTC           1
# 3   1000023983     2021-12-09       2023-07-12 2021-12-09 UTC--2023-07-12 UTC           1
# 4   1000050643     2019-10-14       2020-01-03 2019-10-14 UTC--2020-01-03 UTC           1
# 5   1000050643     2020-08-20       2021-05-17 2020-08-20 UTC--2021-05-17 UTC           1
# 6   1000084050     2017-11-17       2018-06-06 2017-11-17 UTC--2018-06-06 UTC           4
# 7   1000084050     2018-01-16       2018-01-30 2018-01-16 UTC--2018-01-30 UTC           4
# 8   1000084050     2018-03-22       2018-04-05 2018-03-22 UTC--2018-04-05 UTC           4
# 9   1000084050     2018-05-03       2018-05-10 2018-05-03 UTC--2018-05-10 UTC           4
# 10  1000084050     2018-05-29       2018-06-06 2018-05-29 UTC--2018-06-06 UTC           4
# 11  1000084050     2018-06-06       2018-06-06 2018-06-06 UTC--2018-06-06 UTC           4
# 12  1000084050     2018-06-06       2018-06-26 2018-06-06 UTC--2018-06-26 UTC           4
# 13  1000084050     2018-06-28       2018-07-12 2018-06-28 UTC--2018-07-12 UTC           4
# 14  1000150454     2022-03-01       2022-04-21 2022-03-01 UTC--2022-04-21 UTC           1
# 15  1000150454     2022-05-15       2022-08-01 2022-05-15 UTC--2022-08-01 UTC           1
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```r
split(df2, df2$OCLC_Number) %>% ...
```

Side note: `mutate` can have multiple expressions, and they can build on each other. Your `df2 <-` assignment can be simplified a little to

```r
 df2 <- df %>% 
   mutate(
     OCLC_Number = str_replace_all(OCLC_Number, regex(";.*"), ""),
     OCLC_Number = str_replace_all(OCLC_Number, regex(".*?([0-9]+).*"), "\\1"),
     OCLC_Number = as.numeric(as.character(OCLC_Number)),
     Item_Sent_Date = str_replace_all(Item_Sent_Date, regex(" .*"), ""),
     Item_Sent_Date = ymd(Item_Sent_Date),
     Item_Return_Date = str_replace_all(Item_Return_Date, regex(" .*"), ""),
     Item_Return_Date = ymd(Item_Return_Date),
     Interval_Date = interval(Item_Sent_Date, Item_Return_Date)
   ) %>% 
   arrange(OCLC_Number, Item_Sent_Date)
```

While mostly cosmetic, some find that a little easier to read. If you use the `.by=` internal grouping argument to `mutate` (in place of the less-transient `group_by(..)` function) for grouping calculations, doing more calculations in one `mutate(..., .by=c(..))` will be a little more efficient.

(I'm sure some of that can be reduced a little more with nesting ... but I'm going further into subjective and preference, so I'll stop here :-)

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you! And as I've only been in R since July, all of the suggestions are very helpful whether for style, function, etc. I've also noted the comments above about improving the posts in the future. Glad to have joined this community. Thanks again to all!

Comment: You could also use `split(df2, ~OCLC_Number)` or `df2 |> split(~OCLC_Number)` with base R. `split()` now supports a formula syntax as well.

Comment: Nice, thanks @MrFlick, good to know.